# How to add a blank space between header and a ion-card in ionic 2 with some color?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to add a grayspace of between header and the first card starting.
And want to remove the line highlighting on the card's top area in the screen, I have mentioned it the screenshot provided.

**.html**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-toolbar>
    <img>
    <ion-title>Ion Cards</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>

  <ion-card>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img src="img/marty-avatar.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>Marty McFly</h2>
    <p>November 5, 1955</p>
  </ion-item>

  <img src="img/advance-card-bttf.png">

  <ion-card-content>
    <p>Wait a minute. Wait a minute, Doc. Uhhh... Are you telling me that you built a time machine... out of a DeLorean?! Whoa. This is heavy.</p>
  </ion-card-content>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
        <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
        <div>12 Likes</div>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
        <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
        <div>4 Comments</div>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col center text-center>
      <ion-note>
        11h ago
      </ion-note>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7ACk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add the bottom-border in the header.

```
ion-header {
border-bottom: 10px solid gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ionic  is having background white
You can change background in

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-toolbar>
    <img>
    <ion-title>Ion Cards</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content style="background:lightgray;">

  <ion-card>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img src="img/marty-avatar.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>Marty McFly</h2>
    <p>November 5, 1955</p>
  </ion-item>

  <img src="img/advance-card-bttf.png">

  <ion-card-content>
    <p>Wait a minute. Wait a minute, Doc. Uhhh... Are you telling me that you built a time machine... out of a DeLorean?! Whoa. This is heavy.</p>
  </ion-card-content>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
        <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
        <div>12 Likes</div>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
        <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
        <div>4 Comments</div>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col center text-center>
      <ion-note>
        11h ago
      </ion-note>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: please see this picture]

and change header

```
<ion-header style="border-bottom: 5px solid gray;">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <img>
    <ion-title>Ion Cards</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```